# SQL stored procedure- where am I going wrong?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that calculates total revenue from a customer by if it's occupied and the standard rate. I am getting an error message and when I try to call from it I get NULL. Can anyone help? Thanks.

```
//Delimiter
CREATE PROCEDURE calculateRevenue (in customerIDs int, OUT totalRevenue dec(15,2))
    BEGIN 
    SELECT SUM(Occupied*StandardRate) into totalRevenue FROM climatesouth
        WHERE customerIDs = customerID;
    END //
    delimiter//
    
call calculateTotal(10, @totalRevenue);
SELECT @totalRevenue;
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to give your input parameters different names from the columns.  Then you need to use them.  Also, `DELIMITER` goes before the stored procedure definition:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE calculateRevenue (
    in in_customerIDs int, 
    out out_totalRevenue dec(15,2))
BEGIN 
    SELECT SUM(cs.Occupied cs.* cs.StandardRate) into out_totalRevenue
    FROM climatesouth cs
    WHERE cs.customerID = in_customerID;
END //
```

Answer (score 0):

The `delimiter` assignment is off: your are setting it to `//` *after* the `create procedure` statement.

Also, the parameter name needs to be fixed: your are not using the correct name in the query (your parameter has a trailing `'s'`), because of which the procedure will not produce the result you expect.

So:

```
delimiter //  -- change the default delimiter here

create procedure calculaterevenue (in p_customerid int, out p_totalrevenue dec(15,2))
begin 
    select sum(occupied * standardrate) into p_totalrevenue
    from climatesouth
    where customerid = p_customerid; -- "p_customerid" is the parameter name
end //

delimiter ; -- reset the delimiter, now we can call the procedure
    
call calculaterevenue(10, @totalrevenue);
select @totalrevenue;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easier just to return the result as a result set rather than to use the OUT-parameter. The OUT-parameters are usually used only when calling procedure from another procedure. If you call the procedure from your application, use the result set.

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE calculateRevenue (in_customerID int)
BEGIN 
  SELECT SUM(Occupied*StandardRate) as totalrevenue
  FROM climatesouth
  WHERE customerID = in_customerID;
END
//
delimiter ;
call calculateRevenue(10);
```